# How to create an array of SD matrices?

Tags: julia-jump

How do you create an array of (variable)matrices A1,..,AN of semi definite matrices in Julia Jump where N is a parameter? @variable(model,x[1:N]) won't work because this is an array of variables, not of matrix variables.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use the anonymous variable syntax here.

```
@variable(m, [1:N,1:N], SDP)
```

returns one matrix `N x N` of variables which is symmetric and PSD constrained. If you want a collection of `K` of them, just make one:

```
A = [@variable(m, [1:N, 1:N], SDP) for k in 1:K]
```